# How to display data from global state in React?

Tags: reactjs

Hello fellow programmers,

I need the data from the global state displayed on a page. To specify: the user has to see the data he entered in a form and make sure it is correct. Main goal is getting it on the page first.

What is global state? It is where the data from input fields is collected and is able to be edited. Here is an example how I get the data:

```
const [enteredFirstName, setEnteredFirstName] = useState('');
```

In the form it looks like this:

```
<Card>
   <div className="formControl">
       <label htmlFor="first_name">Voornaam</label>
       <input
            type="text"
            id="first_name"
            value={enteredFirstName}
            onChange={event => {
                setEnteredFirstName(event.target.value)
            }}
       />
    </div>
</Card>
```

Card makes sure that the form data will be collected.

```
const Card = props => {
    return <div className="card">{props.children}</div>
};
```

Now I need to display the data. I assume that I have to get the props of the children and 'fetch' the data that way? I have tried tutorials but I can't find anything related to my issue.

This picture illustrates how it is supposed to look:

[image: this is how the data should be displayed]

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to share data between multiple components without having to pass them as props down through all of your components, you can [use Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). That will let you write and read from the context in any components that are wrapped within the context provider.

Answer (score 0):

I've used some of your code and created a sandbox to hopefully replicate the functionality you require.

Please check and let me know if this helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-visvesvaraya-025cf?file=/src/Form.js

EDIT: To answer your question, you can use the original state and pass it down to another component that only renders based on a condition you've set. - In my example, I am passing the state down to the UserData component which will only render when the data has been submitted.